# Rust multiple crates fail to compile due to permission denied

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

When I build a project with dependencies, the build script fails with permission denied. This dosent happen with every crate. Here is the output from when trying to build a WGPU project.

```
error: failed to run custom build command for `objc_exception v0.1.2`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/Users/64001830/wgpu-test/target/debug/build/objc_exception-f7c40ee498546635/build-script-build` (exit status: 1)
  --- stdout
  TARGET = Some("x86_64-apple-darwin")
  OPT_LEVEL = Some("0")
  HOST = Some("x86_64-apple-darwin")
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CC_x86_64-apple-darwin
  CC_x86_64-apple-darwin = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CC_x86_64_apple_darwin
  CC_x86_64_apple_darwin = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_CC
  HOST_CC = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CC
  CC = Some("/usr/bin/")
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CFLAGS_x86_64-apple-darwin
  CFLAGS_x86_64-apple-darwin = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CFLAGS_x86_64_apple_darwin
  CFLAGS_x86_64_apple_darwin = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_CFLAGS
  HOST_CFLAGS = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CFLAGS
  CFLAGS = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS
  CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS = None
  DEBUG = Some("true")
  CARGO_CFG_TARGET_FEATURE = Some("cmpxchg16b,fxsr,llvm14-builtins-abi,sse,sse2,sse3,ssse3")
  running: "/usr/bin/" "-O0" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-gdwarf-2" "-fno-omit-frame-pointer" "-m64" "-arch" "x86_64" "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-o" "/Users/64001830/wgpu-test/target/debug/build/objc_exception-59a44c9c89f7e2b5/out/extern/exception.o" "-c" "extern/exception.m"

  --- stderr


  error occurred: Command "/usr/bin/" "-O0" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-gdwarf-2" "-fno-omit-frame-pointer" "-m64" "-arch" "x86_64" "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-o" "/Users/64001830/wgpu-test/target/debug/build/objc_exception-59a44c9c89f7e2b5/out/extern/exception.o" "-c" "extern/exception.m" with args "bin" failed to start: Os { code: 13, kind: PermissionDenied, message: "Permission denied" }
```

Ive tried restarting, new projects, uninstalling and reinstalling rust.

Comment: Seems either you or some dependency of yours set the ccompiler to `"/usr/bin/"` which can't work because it's a directory not a C compiler. Do you have an environment variable `CC` defined? If so try clearing or changing it to something like `/usr/bin/cc` or similar.

Comment: @cafce25 I do have a variable `CC` defined, I changed it to `/usr/bin/cc` and It worked, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

From the error (specifically this line: `CC = Some("/usr/bin/")`) you can see that the C compiler environment variable (`CC`) is set to `/usr/bin/` which is not a valid C compiler.

You can either clear the environment variable or set it to something useful like `/usr/bin/cc`, `/usr/bin/gcc` or the path to your C compiler of choice.